# How is the order of the names in a UFC fight decided?

Tags: mma, ufc

How is the order of the names in a UFC fight decided?
For instance, why was UFC 289 main event Amanda Nunes vs Irene Aldana and not Irene Aldana vs Amanda Nunes?

The "obvious" rules , such as alphabetic or number of wins seems not to apply, when looking at past UFC fights. Is it perhaps just random?

Comment: At least in the case of Nunes vs Aldana, Nunes is a much more recognisable name for the general public. I suspect this will be negotiated in the fight contract.

Comment: Like Philip, I don't know, but I speculate that it's similar to actors in movies in which one person gets "top billing" as part of their contract negotiation.